# ElasticSearch used in a web service throws OverlappingFileLockException

Tags: java, web-services, elasticsearch

We wrote a library comparing documents using ElasticSearch. It works in a JSF app but not in a webservice.

Both apps have the same logic: First they create a repository (the constructor loads a list of documents from a hardcoded location and indexes it) and then allow the user to compare his own document with those in the repository. The JSF app provides some GUI, but the webservice layer is very thin - it creates the repository on startup (loading and indexing documents) and then just passes comparison requests to the library.

The more complex JSF app works without any problems, while the webservice app does not even load (i.e. it does not even index the documents), having a problem with overlapping locks. (Note that I deploy one or the other app, not both at the same time. No data are shared by the apps. I just mention the JSF app because it works, while the other does not, even though they use the same library.)

What is so different about a JSF app and a webservice that the former works, while the latter does not?

Here are some details (slightly simplified/modified)

The webservice:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "RepositoryWebService")
public class RepositoryWebService {
    private static Repository repository = Repository.getInstance();

    // some web methods (irrelevant since I never get that far)
}

public class Repository {
   private final static Repository instance = new Repository();

   public static Repository getInstance() {
       return instance;
   }
   :
}
```

The JSF app accesses creates a singleton instance of repository as well (using an `@ApplicationScoped` bean).

The exception I get for the webservice is:

```
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
    :
at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1154) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.obtain(NativeFSLockFactory.java:217) [lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1 1362471 - thetaphi - 2012-07-17 12:40:12]
at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:80) [elasticsearch-0.19.11.jar:]
at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.<init>(InternalNode.java:125) [elasticsearch-0.19.11.jar:]
at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159) [elasticsearch-0.19.11.jar:]
at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:166) [elasticsearch-0.19.11.jar:]
at org.abc.Repository.<init>(Repository.java:56) [repository.jar:]
    :
```

In `elasticsearch.yml`, I have (inter alia):

```
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
index:
    number_of_shards: 1
    number_of_replicas: 0
```

I tried both glassfish 3.1.2 and JBoss 7.1.1, with the same results. Both on JDK 1.7.0_07 64bit Windows 7.

Any suggestions what do I do wrong would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

It works when I put all the dependent jars (elasticsearch*, jna*,log4j*, lucene*, snappy-java* and my jar) into the domain's lib directory (on Glassfish). It does not when the jars are only part of the war file.

Not sure what is going on. I though this might be somehow related to the fact that only one instance of native libraries is loaded in java, but putting there only the jna and snappy-java jars was not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will help but here are some thoughts:

- It looks like that you have multiple instances of your webservice class loaded. Are you sure that Repository.getInstance() is working fine?
- I have a demo project (webapp - REST Webservice + embedded ES) that works:  (have a look at this [code](https://github.com/scrutmydocs/scrutmydocs)). I used Spring for this project and the Elasticsearch Spring Factory: [Spring ElasticSearch](https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am pretty sure that the repository is created just once (There is a log statement in the constructor and I see only one such log message in the log).

Comment: @dadoonet, have you tried running multiple instances of your demo project? Does it work? Facing the same issue, when trying to deploy two instances of a war file(with different configuration) in tomcat.

Comment: I don't know (too old thread) but elasticsearch does not support anymore being embedded.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're loading the list after a method call or similar for both the JSF and the Web Service applications. In the last one, you should load the data when you deploy the application. For this, write a `ServletContextListener` and load the data in the `contextInitialized` method.

The `ServletContextListener` will load before all the `Servlet`s are loaded in the Web application. By doing this,all your web service methods will have access to the prepared data.

About `ServletContextListener`:

- [ServletContextListener Example](http://www.javabeat.net/2009/02/servletcontextlistener-example/)

If you need/want to access to the `ServletContext` from the Web Service class, you can do it by setting this sentence

```
@WebService(serviceName = "RepositoryWebService")
public class RepositoryWebService {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext wsContext;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return (ServletContext)wsContext.getMessageContext()
            .get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
    }

    //your web methods here...
}
```

Comment: But that's what he static variable `repository` does automatically - it creates the `Repository` object when the class loader loads `RepositoryWebService`. The constructor of `Repository` loads the documents (it does,  the problem occurs once the indexing starts).

Comment: Are you trying to load the data having both JSF and the Web Service app in the same machine at the same time?

Comment: No. I deploy one or the other. The JSF works, the ws does not.